# Is it possible not having to browse for a file in your computer at an input field of type file, but to take it from another website?

Tags: php, html, input

There is website A that wants me to upload a profile picture. It uses a usual form with `<input type="file">`.

Then there is website B, that has a picture I would like to have in my profile on website A.

But I would like to upload the picture from website B on A, without having to download it on my PC. Instead I would like to change the form on website A with Tampermonkey (as example) so it takes the picture directly from website B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($imageURL));

if (is_resource($image) === true) {
    // image is valid, your code
} else {
    // not a valid image, show error
}
```

See documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php